# Simplifying a LINQ expression that finds the largest date smaller than another date

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ 2 SQL query that needs to run a subquery in the where clause. The subquery just returns the largest date (from a date column) that is less than or equal to another date (an input to the function).

I originally had it like this (not this in the `where` clause of an outer query):

```
skew.CalibrationDate.Date == (from skew2 in db.Skew 
                              where skew2.CalibrationDate.Date <= date.Date 
                              select skew2.CalibrationDate).Max()
```

And then simplified it to:

```
skew.CalibrationDate.Date == db.Skew.Select(s => s.CalibrationDate.Date)
                                    .Where(s => s <= date.Date)
                                    .Max()
```

(note that the `db.Skew` table/object has multiple columns/properties but I'm only interested in the `CalibrationDate` for this clause and also that `date` is an input to the function that this is in, a regular `DateTime` variable).

Is it necessary for me to have all three of the `Select()`, `Where()` and `Max()` calls or is there some redundancy here? Could I put a lambda expression in the `Max()` call to get rid of one of the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
skew.CalibrationDate.Date == db.Skew
    .Where(s => s.CalibrationDate.Date <= date.Date)
    .Max(s => s.CalibrationDate.Date)
```

`Max` will return the maximum value itself, not the object with the maximum date.